# A word or a phrase to describe younger siblings who likes to control her older siblings

Tags: word-request, phrase-usage

A colleague of mime had a younger sibling who likes to control my colleague life.

Is there a word or a phrase to describe it?

Answer (score 1):

We can say:

That child is very *bossy*.

As the child grows older into adulthood, we could say:

His younger sibling (sister, brother) is very *meddlesome*.